# How to override panel close event

Tags: jquery-mobile-panel

I have a jquery mobile panel menu (open) that has links (data-ajax=false) and want to override the default behavior of the panel closing before it navigates away. All of my pages have the panel menu open by default, and it looks bad when they automatically close every time I navigate only to appear open again on the destination page... is there a way to stop the close event?

Comment: Can you confirm you're setting the [dismissible](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-dismissible) option to `false`? (Adding the code and/or markup of your panel to your question would also be a good idea.)

Comment: Yes, it is: div id="div_menu" class="menu" data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-dismissible="false"

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, and found something that seems to work - instead of using `data-ajax="false"`, just put `target="_self"`.  jQuery Mobile doesn't load pages with AJAX if a target is specified, and `"_self"` is just the default.  It also doesn't close panels like `data-ajax="false"` does.